# GitLab でブロックしたユーザにもメールが送信されてしまう

Tags: centos, gitlab

### 前提知識

GitLabでブロックしたユーザには通知メールが飛ばない。
https://gitlab-docs.creationline.com/ee/user/admin_area/blocking_unblocking_users.html
※ 私が使用しているGitLab 12.7.0の公式ドキュメントでもブロックしたユーザには通知メールが飛ばないと記載があった。

### 問題点

GitLabのユーザをブロックしたにも関わらず、そのブロックユーザに通知メール（プッシュ情報等）が飛ぶこと。

`https://localhost/admin/logs`のproduction.logを見ると、以下のようなログが残っていた。

```bash
Sent mail to ブロックしたユーザのメールアドレス (192.9ms)
```

##### 実行環境:

GitLab 12.7.0
CentOS 7.6.1810 (Core)

### 実現したいこと

ブロックしたユーザに通知メールが飛ばないようにする。

### 回答者様へ

全くこの問題の原因がわかっていません。
原因追及のために情報が足りない場合は、遠慮なくお申し付けください。
ご協力お願い致します。

Comment: ログの記録だけでなく、実際にメールが送信されているか (該当ユーザーが受信しているか) は確認済みなのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。該当ユーザがメールを受信していることは確認済みです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 自己解決

以下のページの「Recipients」に記載しているメールアドレスに、ブロックしたユーザと同じメールアドレスが登録されていたので、ブロックしたユーザにもメールが届いてました。
`https://localhost/groupName/projectName/-/services/emails_on_push/edit`